# CakePHP Blog Database Schema

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, blogs

I'm new to CakePHP and struggling to make a complete blog with Posts, Tags, comments and users with role. I need to know the perfect schema based upon the CakePHP convention so that utilizing that I could bake most of the CRUD code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog schema](https://github.com/neilcrookes/CakePHP-Blog-Plugin/blob/master/Config/schema/schema.sql) looks promising. It is missing the users' table and relationships, so you will have to add the fk of `user_id` to the necessary tables.

here is a sample users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL, -- OR `username`
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```